# Getting the page height from a WinForms WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I've been trying for the last few days to get the height of a web page from the Document property of a `WebBrowser` control.

Here's my latest attempt.

```
HtmlElementCollection children = webBrowser.Document.All;
int maxOffset = 0;


foreach (HtmlElement child in children) {
    int bottom = 0;
    bottom = child.OffsetRectangle.Bottom;
    if (bottom > maxOffset) {
        maxOffset = bottom;
        pageHeight = maxOffset;
    }
}
```

I've tried to work out the max height of the page by finding the offset bottom of the lowest element in the page.

The problem is this over shoots the actual length of the page by about 500px in most cases.

Anyone got any ideas? I can't believe how hard it is just to get the height of a page!

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
```

Comment: Okie, but when the page is hosted in a different machine it is not working. If the page is hosted in my local machine both height and width are rendered correctly. Any insights?

Comment: Ever tried this on http://www.regular-expressions.info/ ? It returns 122 as scroll height but @Morgeh code does it Right

Comment: That is because regular-expressions.info is using iFrames. The top header is in a separate frame and the content below is in a different iFrame. Don't know how to make it work with iFrames.

Comment: Works perfectly well. One needs to make sure the document is fully loaded when attempting this.

Comment: @NLV: are you sure that "hosting in a different machine" didn't simply cause slower loading and your document wasn't ready to report its height (unlike faster local server / web page)?

Answer (score 1):

Find the **BODY** tag and get the **OffsetRectangle.Bottom** of that element.  This will give you the height of the page.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It always gives me the size of the browser control, not of the contents

Answer (score 0):

`webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height`
gave me a cut off page. idk why.

i did it like this.

loop elements select max height/width. i used this after documentCompleted event

```
    //fit to content  -get size **after documentCompleted**
    var wbAll = webBrowser.Document.All.Cast<HtmlElement>();
    var maxWidth = wbAll.Max(x => Math.Max(x.ClientRectangle.Width, x.ScrollRectangle.Width));
    var maxHeight =wbAll.Max(x => Math.Max(x.ClientRectangle.Height, x.ScrollRectangle.Height));

    webBrowser.Height = maxHeight;
    webBrowser.Width = maxWidth;
```

Comment: Its NOT accurate though.