# Get the Y axis height of WebBrowser control document

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the height of a document in a web browser control.

At the moment i'm using the code below but it always returns 622 and i know my documents are all different sizes.

```
private void webCompareSQL_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmldoc = webCompareSQL.Document;
           int ScrollHight = htmldoc.Window.Position.Y;
        }
```

Can someone please show me the right way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the page height from a WinForms WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785737/getting-the-page-height-from-a-winforms-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].OffsetRectangle.Bottom;
```

OR

```
webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
```

OR

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].OffsetRectangle.Height;
```

For 3rd case result is the height of the WebBrowser view window + borders.

**Edited:**

Comment: Ok thanks will check it out the first option you gave me only returns 1930 for all my documents?

Comment: getElementsbyTagName is underlined in red?

Comment: Plz can you tel me why GetElementsByTagName is underlined in red?

Comment: Height is always 175 even tho all my docs are different lengths?

Comment: I need to be measuring the displayed text length inside the doc?

Comment: ("html") could be better, but it still all returns the value 175?

Comment: Still all 175? is this mesuring the size of my web browser control or what? because i need it to mesure the scroll bar total height

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12840/discussion-between-talha-and-pomster)

Comment: webPrevSQL.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom; seams to work, there is just a lot of left over space??